# When extending a THREE.js "class", why do I need to invoke the .call(this) method from within the new object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating an object that I want to inherit from THREE.Object3D(). My code is as follows:

```
function myNewObject() {
  THREE.Object3D.call(this);

  //...

}

myNewObject.prototype = new THREE.Object3D();
myNewObject.prototype.constructor = myNewObject;
```

My question is: why do I need to invoke 'THREE.Object3D.call(this)' from within myNewObject()? Isn't it enough that I'm assigning the prototype to a THREE.Object3D() object?

Answer (score 0):

This is typical Javascript subclassing, though you should really call:

```
THREE.myNewObject.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Object3D.prototype );
THREE.myNewObject.prototype.constructor = THREE.myNewObject;
```

rather than `new THREE.Object3D()`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't really answer my question.